# $P$-adic Numbers Least Close to One

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

If I understand the definition of $p$-adic numbers, then the numbers that are $2$-adically least close to one are $3, 7, 11, \ldots$ because they are divisible by $2^1$.

Do the two-adic numbers, which least close to one; $3, 7, 11, \ldots$ form an arithmetic series with a difference of four?

Comment: You’re talking about $2$-adic integers only, right? You do realize that there are oodles of $2$-adic integers that aren’t in $\Bbb Z$, right? I’m not sure what an “arithmetic series” might be in this context. Finally, any “even” number (like zero) is a lot farther from $1$ than $3$ is.

Comment: Well no, I think I was thinking of natural numbers. I did not know that some integers are not in the set of Z, which is the set of integers. If I begin with 3 minus 1, I can divide that evenly by two to the one. Seven is the next number that satisfies that, and eleven is the next number. It appears to be an arithmetic series. Or maybe I'm too ignorant to ask the question.

Answer (score 3):

So: I see that you’re just beginning. Welcome to the $p$-adic world! It’s in many ways easier than the real-complex world: I think of $\Bbb Z_p$ and $\Bbb Q_p$ as a friendly world to live in.

But you have to learn the basics. You may, if you wish, think of the $p$-adic integers $\Bbb Z_p$ as the completion of the natural numbers $\Bbb N$ with respect to the $p$-adic metric. But you must recognize that the act of completion brings along many many quantities that are not natural integers (like $-1$); nor rational integers at all (like $p/(p+1)\,$); nor even rational numbers (like $\sqrt{-7}\in\Bbb Z_2$ or $\sqrt{p^2+1}\in\Bbb Z_p$ for $p\ne2$); nor even algebraic numbers, for which I can’t give a ready example, though I presume that $\log(1+p^2)$ would do.

Where to learn the basics? The best book I’ve seen is the text by Gouvêa; there are a number of others. Read, and learn, and, I repeat, be welcome!